# Matlab "Patch" equivalent in scilab

Tags: matlab, plot, scilab

I need to plot a quad face in Scilab with the command Plot3d, but I am unable to find a way to assign a color at the vertex, proportional to a real value.

In the patch command in Matlab, I can assign a color at the vertex, proportional to a value given by a real number (for example, a vertex with a value of 3.6 will have a different color than a vertex with a value of 3.2).

In scilab, it seems that the plot3D is able to manage only integer values.

I tried the following code:

```
    xf = [0, 1; 1 ,2; 1, 2; 0, 1 ];
    yf = [1, 1;1, 2;1, 1;1, 1 ];
    zf = [0, 0 ; 0, 0; 5,5 ;5, 5 ];
colors = [1 1;2 2 ;3.5 3;4.5 4 ];
plot3d(xf,yf,list(zf,colors) ,[0,0,0,flag,3] )
```

but the colors are the same, even if the values specified in the matrix colors are slightly different.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `colors` argument given are used as indices (thus integer) to lookup the color in the colormap.  And that is why they are the same.

In your example you could scale your `color` list and set a large colormap that has more values. For instance

```
//Assuming default flags
flags=[2,8,4]
xf = [0, 1; 1 ,2; 1, 2; 0, 1 ];
yf = [1, 1;1, 2;1, 1;1, 1 ];
zf = [0, 0 ; 0, 0; 5,5 ;5, 5 ];

colors = [1 1;2 2 ;3.5 3;4.5 4 ];
// Scale colors
max_value = max(colors)
nr_of_colors = 128
scaled_colors = colors / max_value * nr_of_colors

plot3d(xf,yf,list(zf,scaled_colors) ,[0,0,0,flag,3] )

// Set colormap
fig = gcf()
fig.color_map = hotcolormap(nr_of_colors)

// To show the current colormap
getcolor()
```

Would result in a more continuous colormap which would reflect slightly different colors

[image: Continuous colormap]